# How to avoid repeating a field value in access query result

Tags: database

I have the below tables in my DB.

Orders:

```
OrderNo.........ItemNo........OrderQty

1000________10_________10

2000________20_________10
```

VendorPO:

```
OrderNo.........ItemNo........VendorPO........POQty

1000________10_________100__________5

2000________20_________100__________7

2000________20_________200__________3
```

And I used this Query:

```
SELECT Order.OrderNo, Order.ItemNo, Order.OrderQty, VendorPO.VendorPO, VendorPO.POQty
FROM [Order] 
INNER JOIN VendorPO ON (Order.ItemNo = VendorPO.ItemNo) 
AND (Order.OrderNo = VendorPO.OrderNo);
```

With these results:

Query Result

```
OrderNo.........ItemNo........OrderQty........VendorPO........POQty
1000________10__________10_________100__________5

2000________20__________10_________100__________7

2000________20__________10_________200__________3
```

I want to avoid repetition of the quantity in the query result, where Item quantity 10 is repeated twice against two PO reference with POQty 3 and 7.

I appreciate your support on finding a way to avoid order quantity repetition.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? And are you using any specific SQL server that you're ok with your answers being specific to?

Comment: Just like Jay said - what are you looking for in terms of output...you have different VendorPO numbers...so I could answer this like 3 different ways, if you don't want to show the Vendor PO then remove it and do a sum(POQty) but depends on your desired output

Comment: Hi Jay and Brian, thanks for your response... i am using MS Access 2010, in my desired output I want to show order quantity only once. But  the mentioned query repeats order quantity and its wrongly 1000 where as actual Sales Order Quantity is 10

Comment: Hi Brian, hope you got my intent, for your specific question I need to share both Vendor POs as well because an additional info for Vendor POs (which I have not shared in the question) is "Vendor delivery commitment" which would depend on vendor PO. –